# Pass type to generic method determined by Type object

Tags: c#, generics

I have generic method of an object that I want to invoke. But I have no clue of T in that moment, all I know is type of T which is set to a property of the object.

```
public calass SomeClass{

    public Type SomeType { get; set; }

    public void SomeMethod<T>(){

    }    
}
```

...

```
var instance = new SomeClass();
```

...

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
instance.SomeMethod<SomeType>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call it using `Reflection:`

```
var method = instance.GetType().GetMethod("SomeMethod")
             .MakeGenericMethod(instance.SomeType);

method.Invoke(instance);
```

Also note that `SomeType` is the name of your property, not the type of your property.You need to specify the type when you want to call a generic method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following check in SomeMethod<T>:

```
if (!SomeType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) throw new Exception("Expecting type stored in SomeType.");
```

Or I would change the class to templated:

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{
    public Type InstanceType { get { return typeof(T); } }

    public void SomeMethod<T> () { }
}
```